# Handle nonexistent PWD gracefully

Tags: exception, crystal-lang, pwd

Whenever I execute a crystal program in a directory that does not exists, it fails with `Unhandled exception: getcwd: No such file or directory (Errno)`. I can't find the way to handle such case gracefully, is it possible?

Comment: The problem happens because we have a non-documented constant `Dir::INITIAL_PWD` which is set to `Dir.current` and that's executed at startup. We should probably fix that. But right now I don't think there's a way to handle that case. Please open a bug report.

Comment: The issue is opened: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/7198